# Chrome webdriver selenium memory error- python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I was trying to test selenium and chrome webdriver by creating a script that will open up the browser to a specific site.

Here is my code below:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def open_browser(user_string):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(user_string)

def main():
    x = input("Where would you like to open the internet to? ")
    open_browser(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I run this in the shell, a blank window opens for a few seconds then closes and I get these errors:

```
124:63332:1022/202611.560:ERROR:persistent_memory_allocator.cc(815)]
Corruption detected in shared-memory segment.

124:60160:1022/202621.325:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to
create shader cache entry: -2
```

I have no idea what could be causing these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put 'chromedriver.exe' inside script folder which is inside python folder on your installed driver(by default C://Python/script), then add C://Python and C://Python/script in path under environment variable. Follow the step [here](http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2015/08/16/setting-up-python-in-windows-10/) for more detail. After the setup restart once and then try your code

Comment: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see ht
tps://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home  Is what I get so it seems that I may not have correctly added it to my path for windows 10. Windows 10 has an extra step when Adding it to the path that tutorials dont show so that may be where I messed up

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct so that is will be useful for other.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me. Check that you have the correct version of chromedriver in your path.
Otherwise, try deleting the shadercache: `~/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/` (or on Windows `C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\`)